# How much information is required to determine integers x,y,z

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples

> what is x+y+z is x,y and z are integers and xy-1 is divisible by z, yz-1 is divisible by x and xz-1 is divisible by y.

Answer (score 1):

It could be any integer: for $x+y+z=s \ne 2$, try $x=1,\;y=1,\;z=s-2$, or for $x+y+z=2$, try $x=-1,\; y=2,\; z=1$.